# Cueblocks sitemap doesn't capture all products

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, sitemaps

Recently my company upgraded our websites to Magento2.4.4 and the sitemaps generated by the module Cueblocks suddenly stopped capturing all products.

We have over 10000 products in stock, yet sitemap only captures less than 3000 products. I have discovered an error in the code which I fixed, yet the problem still persists. I have tried deleting the sitemap and re-generating them with no avail. Not sure what might be happening. There are no errors in the log and each sitemap generation is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that all 10000 product is set to visible, enable, and assign to the website

Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although it doesn't apply for all products,the products that have these attributes are more than what the sitemap.xml has captured. There was some deprecated functionalities that I have fixed in cueblocks module but it didn't fix the issue.